# difference between transfer speeds through an USB 3.0 hub and without it

Tags: usb, hub, transfer-rate

i have a portable hard disk (superspeed USB 3.0). when i move a big movie file from my laptop to the hard disk connected to the USB 3.0 port in my laptop, the maximum transfer speed is around 70 megabytes per second. (please note that there are no other devices connected to the other USB 3.0 port on my laptop during the transfer). the same transfer of the same file using the same setup except that this time, it is through a portable self-powered hub (advertised as USB 3.0) gives around 42 megabytes per second maximum. (please note that there are no other devices connected to the other USB 3.0 port on my laptop or the hub during the transfer) is this normal? or is it that the portable hub i newly bought is actually an USB 2.0 one being marketed to deceive people? thanks in advance to anyone helping me :)

Comment: You can check if it supports USB 3.0 with [UsbTreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html). I've seen fake USB 2.0 hubs that actually had a USB 2.0 port facing the PC, but device-side ports were USB 1.1.

Comment: 3.0 or 2.0, Hubs are really messy, @naveen. We have had very unpleasant experiences using them. You should stick to connecting External Electronic Devices directly to the Machine during Intensive Input-Output Operations.

Comment: @gronostaj that was indeed helpful. it turns out to be USB 2.0 only. i am returning it. thanks a lot :)

DOBRESCU_Mihai ok

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it supports USB 3.0 with [UsbTreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html).

1. Make sure *Options* → *Jump to new devices* is enabled.
2. Connect the hub, it will be selected in UsbTreeView.
3. Inspect ports of the selected hub. USB 3.0 ports have an "S" icon next to them and *Usb300: 1 (yes)* in the *SupportedUsbProtocols* section when selected.

USB 2.0 hub:

[image: Screenshot showing the "H" icon and Usb300: 0 (no)]

USB 3.0 hub:

[image: Screenshot showing the "S" icon and Usb300: 1 (yes)]

<sub>(comment expanded into answer)</sub>

Comment: very grateful for the detailed help with screenshots. i looked for these and the hub turns out to be USB 2.0 only. thanks a ton :)